# chrome settings disabled for microphone, camera and location for a website

Tags: google-chrome, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am developing a website which requires camera and microphone for communication.
The site uses Twilio communication for audio/video calls.
Twilio device setup is failing and is giving an error as:

Twilio.Exception: twilio.js 1.3+ SDKs require WebRTC/ORTC browser support.         For more information, see https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js.         If you have any questions about this announcement, please contact         Twilio Support at .

To which I tried to debug and found that for my website in Google settings, microphone, camera and location settings are set to **Block** and is **Disabled**.

I have tried,

1. Resetting the Chrome browser
2. Upgrading to latest version of Chrome
3. Re-installing the Browser

But to no success.

This is how the chrome settings looks like:

[image: Settings are blocked]
**Note**: This seems to happening on 2 of my laptops, although on some machines it is working properly and the settings to these items is **Allow** in those machines. I have a customer demo and will have to use my laptop for it.

***Any help is highly appreciated!***

Answer (score 2):

The getUserMedia API which allows access to the camera and microphone requires a secure context, i.e. https. See [this blog post](https://tokbox.com/blog/the-impact-of-googles-new-chrome-security-policy-on-webrtc/) for background information. Recent versions of Chrome do not make getUserMedia available on http anymore.

Switch to https which should work out of the box on Heroku.